# How to offset Directions route Polyline to the side of the map canvas?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently I'm working on a direction based project and I want to push my direction to the right side when rendered.
This is what I'm getting.
[image]

I don't want to get directions behind the panel.
This is what I want to get.
[image]

Direction between two point to the right side.

My code to render directions between two points is as follows

```
renderDirections(): void {
    var placeID = this.destinationPlaceId.getPlace();
    console.log(placeID.place_id);
    this.destinationPlaceId = placeID.place_id;
    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    let directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: false
    });
    initMap();
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

    placeID = this.startPlaceID.getPlace();
    console.log(placeID.place_id);
    this.originPlaceId = placeID.place_id;
    directionsService.route(
        {
            origin: { 'placeId': this.originPlaceId },
            destination: { 'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId },
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[this.travelMode]
        },
        function (response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready-made function to achieve this but it is feasible, as long as you know the width (and position) of your top layer.

#### Here is how you can do it:

1. Plot a route on the map and listen for the map `idle` event before starting with the offset process.
2. Check the leftmost point of the route bounds to see if it falls behind the overlay. This makes use of the `fromLatLngToPoint()` method to translate from lat/lng coordinates to a point on the map projection.
3. Check how much you can offset the route by comparing the leftmost and rightmost points of the route with the available space on the map. Offset the map until both points fit on the available canvas space.
4. If both points cannot fit within the map canvas, zoom out and start the same process again.
5. The script must be aware of the width of the overlay and you should apply some margins so that it always fits well.

#### Working code snippet:

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
var start, end;
var map;
var routeBounds = false;
var overlayWidth = 200; // Width of the overlay DIV
var leftMargin = 30; // Grace margin to avoid too close fits on the edge of the overlay
var rightMargin = 80; // Grace margin to avoid too close fits on the right and leave space for the controls

overlayWidth += leftMargin;

function initialize() {

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    start = new google.maps.LatLng(48.857380, 2.351717);
    end = new google.maps.LatLng(50.108814, 8.672309);

    var btn1 = document.getElementById('calcRoute');
    btn1.addEventListener('click', calcRoute);

    var btn2 = document.getElementById('offsetMap');
    btn2.addEventListener('click', offsetMap);

    var btn3 = document.getElementById('fitAndOffsetMap');
    btn3.addEventListener('click', fitAndOffsetMap);

    var btn4 = document.getElementById('fitMap');
    btn4.addEventListener('click', fitMap);

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true
    });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: start,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        }
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function offsetMap() {

    if (routeBounds !== false) {

        // Clear listener defined in directions results
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'idle');

        // Top right corner
        var topRightCorner = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng());

        // Top right point
        var topRightPoint = fromLatLngToPoint(topRightCorner).x;

        // Get pixel position of leftmost and rightmost points
        var leftCoords = routeBounds.getSouthWest();
        var leftMost = fromLatLngToPoint(leftCoords).x;
        var rightMost = fromLatLngToPoint(routeBounds.getNorthEast()).x;

        // Calculate left and right offsets
        var leftOffset = (overlayWidth - leftMost);
        var rightOffset = ((topRightPoint - rightMargin) - rightMost);

        // Only if left offset is needed
        if (leftOffset >= 0) {

            if (leftOffset < rightOffset) {

                var mapOffset = Math.round((rightOffset - leftOffset) / 2);

                // Pan the map by the offset calculated on the x axis
                map.panBy(-mapOffset, 0);

                // Get the new left point after pan
                var newLeftPoint = fromLatLngToPoint(leftCoords).x;

                if (newLeftPoint <= overlayWidth) {

                    // Leftmost point is still under the overlay
                    // Offset map again
                    offsetMap();
                }

            } else {

                // Cannot offset map at this zoom level otherwise both leftmost and rightmost points will not fit
                // Zoom out and offset map again
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
                offsetMap();
            }
        }
    }
}

function fromLatLngToPoint(latLng) {

    var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
    var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());
    var worldCoordinateNW = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(nw);
    var worldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);

    return new google.maps.Point(Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x - worldCoordinateNW.x) * scale), Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y - worldCoordinateNW.y) * scale));
}

function calcRoute() {

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            // Define route bounds for use in offsetMap function
            routeBounds = response.routes[0].bounds;

            // Write directions steps
            writeDirectionsSteps(response.routes[0].legs[0].steps);

            // Wait for map to be idle before calling offsetMap function
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

                // Offset map
                offsetMap();
            });

            // Listen for directions changes to update bounds and reapply offset
            google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {

                // Get the updated route directions response
                var updatedResponse = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

                // Update route bounds
                routeBounds = updatedResponse.routes[0].bounds;

                // Fit updated bounds
                map.fitBounds(routeBounds);

                // Write directions steps
                writeDirectionsSteps(updatedResponse.routes[0].legs[0].steps);

                // Offset map
                offsetMap();
            });
        }
    });
}

function writeDirectionsSteps(steps) {

    var overlayContent = document.getElementById("overlayContent");
    overlayContent.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {

        overlayContent.innerHTML += '<p>' + steps[i].instructions + '</p><small>' + steps[i].distance.text + '</small>';
    }
}

function fitMap() {

    if (routeBounds !== false) {

        map.fitBounds(routeBounds);
    }
}

function fitAndOffsetMap() {

    if (routeBounds !== false) {

        map.fitBounds(routeBounds);
        offsetMap();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 160px;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#overlayContent {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#overlayContent p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 6px 0;
}
small {
    font-size: 9px;
}
#overlayContent small {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
i {
    color: lightblue;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
button {
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="overlayContent">
         <h1>DIV OVERLAY</h1>

         <h5>Routes should not be drawn below this element.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Calc route</i> button to draw the directions route.</h5>

         <h5><i>Map offset</i> will be applied automatically.</h5>

         <h5><i>Drag the route</i> to see how it is applied.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Offset map</i> button to reapply the offset.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Fit only</i> button to only fit route bounds.</h5>

         <h5>Click the <i>Fit and offset map</i> button to fit to route bounds and reapply offset.</h5>

    </div>
</div>
<button id="calcRoute">Calc route</button>
<button id="offsetMap">Offset map</button>
<button id="fitMap">Fit only</button>
<button id="fitAndOffsetMap">Fit and offset map</button>


<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

#### Working fiddle:

You can play with it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rat1fkkc/) as it is easier to see the behavior, resize the window, etc.